# Allow anonymous access to specific URL in Symfony firewall protected bundle

Tags: symfony, firewall

I have a Symfony bundle which can only be accessible by using `mydomain.com/box`

To access /box you must be logged in, however i would like to enable anonymous access into `mydomain.com/box/download`

```
# Security.yml
access_control:
    - { path: ^/box , roles: ROLE_USER}
```

How can i do ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
# security.yml
access_control:
    - { path: ^/box/download , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
    - { path: ^/box , roles: ROLE_USER}
```

Symfony2 firewalls are processed in order, and only first matching one will be applied. Therefore, if you put the /box/download before /box, the /box/download rule will be processed and the rest will be ignored.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

Answer (score 7):

**Symfony 6**

As of Symfony 6 you need to use the role `PUBLIC_ACCESS` instead of `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`.

https://symfony.com/doc/6.0/security.html#allowing-unsecured-access-i-e-anonymous-users