# Can I mark a single URI endpoint as anonymous?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-security

I have read the docs and followed this similar question:

[Allow anonymous access to specific URL in symfony firewall protected bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406764/allow-anonymous-access-to-specific-url-in-symfony-firewall-protected-bundle#)

Using Symfony 4.1.4 I have tried the following:

```
access_control:
  - { path: ^/rpi/service/application/quote/approve, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
  - { path: ^/rpi, roles: ROLE_USER }
  - { path: ^/erp, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

However when I access the first URI as anonymous I am prompted by the `http_basic_ldap` login screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
anonymous: true
```

in your firewall, as in the default configuration config/packages/security.yml:

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
```

Anonymous authentication means that the user *is* authenticated and *has* a token, but it is an anonymous token.

If you do not have anonymous: true, the AnonymousAuthenticationListener will never run for your firewall, and never create an anonymous token.